# Design question: how to do "UserControls" in Android dev? Trying to avoid one large .java file with all code in it

Tags: android, user-controls

Coming from a Visual Studio/WinForms background, I face the problem of how to avoid placing all code in one large .java-file when developing for Android.

In WinForms its very easy to create a new UserControl that contains both layout and code to handle a certain task. This way the code doesnt have to be places in one large file, but can be "modularized" of sorts.

How to achieve the same thing in Android dev? As an example, I have my MainActivity.java that all code is contained in. Now, I want to scan for Bluetooth devices. A popup should appear during scan and whenever a device is found, I want a list (in the popup) to be populated with the info of the BT device.

So, from the click of a Button I can do .startDiscovery(), but I really want all of that code to be elsewhere, not in my main .java file. It should be separate, including all event listeners. None of that (hooking events etc) should be in MainActivity, it should all be placed in the "userControl" (and as you probably understand, there are many good reasons for that)

What is the best approach for this? Am i going abouit this the correct way?
** EDIT 2011-09-05 **

So I added a class, BluetoothTest.java, to handle everything as described in this post.  However, its not working very well. The popup doesnt show. Am I doing this correctly?

```
package com.sdkexample;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;

public class BluetoothTest {

    private Context ct;
    private View parentView;
    public BluetoothTest(Context ct, View parentView)
    {
        this.ct = ct;
        this.parentView = parentView;
    }

    public void start()
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ct.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View btView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_bluetoothsearch, null);
        final ListView lv = (ListView)btView.findViewById(R.id.listViewBtDevices);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ct, R.id.twoLineListItem1));
        PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(btView);
        pw.showAtLocation(parentView, Gravity.CENTER, 100, 100);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
        }
        else
        {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                mBluetoothAdapter.enable();

            final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    String action = intent.getAction();

                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                        // 
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                        ArrayAdapter aa = (ArrayAdapter)lv.getAdapter();
                        aa.add(device.toString());

                        if (device.getName()== "DPP-350")
                        {
                            // ***
                            // HERE I WANT TO ADD THE DEVICE TO MY LIST IN MY POPUP!
                            // ***
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            ct.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        }
    }

}
```

**--- EDIT ---**

[This page](http://www.mobilemancer.com/2011/01/08/popup-window-in-android/) describes some stuff. My problem with that post is that, like I described above, the code is all contained in the "parent"; it is not contained in a form of UserControl.

The "parent" has all the references for the elements in his popup (it saves for example the TextView as mResultText), another unwanted thing. The point is that the popup should be "independent", so that it can be used from any Activity. I should have to implement separate code for each and every popup I want to use

**---**

Here is the code I want to use for discovery:

```
private void SearchPrinter()
{
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
    }
    else
    {
        final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // 
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

                    if (device.getName()== "DPP-350")
                    {
                        // ***
                        // HERE I WANT TO ADD THE DEVICE TO MY LIST IN MY POPUP!
                        // ***
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be a problem at all. Android is based on Java which is an OOP language by design. You need to create separate class to represent the BluetoothListPopUp. In that class you could add all the relevant methods related to the pop up such as addToList() that you will call from  MainActivity.java

The steps are:

1. Create a class BluetoothListPopUp as your PopUp (probably extension of [PopUpWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html))
2. Also create the layout for this popup in separate xml file
3. Add all the methods specific to BluetoothListPopUp including one to add the list
4. Instantiate this class in your MainActivity.java
5. Upon onReceive(), you call the method in BluetoothListPopup to add the device to the list.

Comment: I want it all to be contained in another file. I do not want MainActivity to call anything, not addToList or anything like that. It should all be handled by my "UserControl". What I wanted to do, WinForms-style, is to create the GUI/UserControl and then let it do the rest (ie start looking for BT, updating the list etc)... The only thing MainActivity should do is to create/Start the "UserControl"...

Comment: I just updated the answer. In Android you need to hook the event/listeners manually via the code.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I dont have a problem hooking listerenrs/events. What I do not want is that MainActivity needs to be calling AddToList or anything else. I want the GUI and code for the Bluetooth-thing to be completely separate from MainActivity (and everytjhing else). So, I really just want to *MyBluetoothTHing bt = new MyBluetoothThing(); bt.Show();* and then, the MyBluetoothThing takes care for the rest.

Comment: Without the need to call any method from the MainActivity,  your only options is to start discovery (SearchPrinter()) in the constructor of BluetoothPopUp. This is not the pattern I am seeing/using in Android but not completely illegal as well. We normally call something from the MainActivity to start the process in other control.

Comment: Thanks momo. I updated my post slightly, to point out my issue more clearly. Its a bit weird that the "parent" must implement specific code for each and every popup I have. The popups (or whatever really) should be made independet of who is creating it, ie. "moduleize it".

Comment: Also; if you dont use "independent" controls, that means that if you want to use a Popup in one Activity, you must create all logical code to support it in each and every Activity you call it from. So a scan for BT devices must be implemented in every Activity you want to be able to do that from, instead of having 1 independent UserControl that can be called from anywhere, without additional code?

Comment: I think if you phrase the question as whether your UserControl should call the methods first to get started or leave it as an independent entity that you just instantiate (and let constructors handle the calls), you will have a wider range of answers and it certainly becomes a bit more subjective. In my personal view, there are use cases where you could use either approach and there are use cases where one is better than the other. For your case, I think we could choose either approach. If you want to do code it as an independent entity, then putting the logic in constructor will enable that.

Comment: Yes, sure. If the constructor calls a method, or someone else is not the main issue. It is just that the code/logic should all be contained =)

Answer (score 0):

in your activity create an instance of a class.The class constructor will do all the needed operations SearchPrinter() startDiscovery etc. I can't think of another way seperating your code.

**UPDATE**

From this other class you can have access to all the GUI elements. You can do that by passing a Context reference (`getApplicationContext()`) or the widget itself.

Comment: Well, sure. But that doesnt really contain the GUI. I want all the hooks for events and updating the ListView to be contained in the "UserControl". That I cannot do with a normal class; it must be connected somehow to the GUI and also be started from the MainActivity

Comment: @Ted It does you can pass the Context to the constructor by getApplicationContext()

Comment: I tried this, and its not really working the way I want to. My class has a method, *start()*, that should display a PopupWindow and also handle the Bluetooth scan. I do not see the PopupWindow at all...?